# Compare attribute always validate on the first element of my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Please help on the problem stated above.

Heres my view

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.UserName) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.UserName) 
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.Password) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.Password) 
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.ConfirmPassword) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.ConfirmPassword) 
    </div>
```

Here is my model

```
public abstract partial class Member
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Applied")]
    public System.DateTime? DateApplied { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Membered")]
    public System.DateTime? DateMembered { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Member Type")]
    public int MemberTypeFlag { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}


public class Person : Member
{
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Of Birth")]
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And my viewmodel..

```
public class PersonInformation
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public Address premiseAddress { get; set; }
    public Address billingAddress { get; set; }
 }
```

In this case.. my confirm password will validate on my username element in the view..

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Since my first element in the view is the username field.. my confirm password field will validate on that field and not on the password field.

My code will produce something like this.

```
 USERNAME : ADMIN
 PASSWORD : PASSWORD
 CONFIRM  : PASSWORD **<< this will states that "The password and confirmation password do not match."
```

BUT if I input something like this

```
 USERNAME : ADMIN
 PASSWORD : PASSWORD
 CONFIRM  : ADMIN
```

The validation error is gone., but it should not supposed to behave like that.

Heres the generated HTMLcode..

```
    <div class="editor-label">

        <label for="person_Password">Password</label>

    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">

        <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Password must be at least 6 characters long." data-val-length-max="100" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-required="The Password field is required." id="person_Password" name="person.Password" type="password" value="" /> 

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="person.Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 

    </div>



    <div class="editor-label">

        <label for="person_ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>

    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">

        <input class="text-box single-line password" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="The password and confirmation password do not match." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="person_ConfirmPassword" name="person.ConfirmPassword" type="password" value="" /> 

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="person.ConfirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span> 

    </div>
```

The controller

```
    public ActionResult PersonInformation()
    {
        var pi = new PersonInformation();
        pi.MemberContacts = pi.LoadMemberContacts();
        return View(pi);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersonInformation(PersonInformation member)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            db.Apply(member, out createStatus);
            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                IEnumerable<MemberRequirement> mr = member.person.MemberRequirements;

                return View("Requirements", mr);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }

        }
        return View(member);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `confirm password will validate on my username element in the view`? I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: Can you please publish generated HTML?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov

I edited the question for the illustration.

Comment: @CodeRush Just pasted the HTML code on my question. thanks

Comment: Could you show the signature of the controller action you are posting this form to?

Comment: Few more questions. Why member is a partial class? Is there another Member class that contains more fields? Can we simplify this by removing/renaming username property to see whether it affects validation?

Comment: Also, can you please add [Required] attribute to the ConfirmPassword? This is a view model for registration, so assumption is that in order to register, you always need to provide password and password confirmation. ONce the user registered, you can then create a different view and view model for changing password.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Just added my membership controller at the end part of the question. thanks

Comment: @CodeRush It is a partial class, because I have a person and business entity which both can be a member. If there some better way to do it, let me know. Also tried to put [Required] attribute but no help.

Comment: My observation is, what ever field comes first on my view, it is where my confirmation field will be validated. So if I put an email element first on my view, then it will be validated on my email field.